# Calling Arrays in Verilog Structural Description

Tags: verilog

I am trying to pass only partial arrays from one verilog module to another and encounter an error every time i modify the code.

The code is as follows:

module 1:

```
module Koge_4(A,B,Cin,S,Cout);
input [3:0] A,B;
input Cin;
output [3:0]S;
output Cout;
```

Module 2:

```
module Koge_64(A,B,Cin,S,Cout);
input [63:0]A,B;
input Cin;
output [63:0]S;
output Cout;
wire [15:0]c;
Koge_4 K1  ([3:0]A,[3:0]B,Cin,[3;0]S,c[0]); // sample structural code
```

I am basically trying to call the 4 bit (module 1) for every 4 bit of the input vector in module 2. Hence calling it 16 times for 64 bits.

Comment: Also make sure to set the file type to System Verilog.

Comment: @Oldfart I'm using only verilog not system verilog

Comment: @toolic tried it did not work. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Array as ports are not support in Verilog, only in System Verilog.

Comment: @Oldfart will try it thank you.

Comment: @Oldfart there are no arrays in the example, just vectors. they **are** supported in verilog.

Comment: @toolic this worked thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `endmodule` in the example and have complete mess with verilog syntax (see toolic's comment). Please read a Verilog tutorial.

Here is a cleaned up version of your code which you can compile.

```
module Koge_4(A,B,Cin,S,Cout);
   input [3:0] A,B;
   input Cin;
   output [3:0]S;
   output Cout;
endmodule

module Koge_64(A,B,Cin,S,Cout);
   input [63:0]A,B;
   input Cin;
   output [63:0]S;
   output Cout;

   wire [15:0]c;

   Koge_4 K1  (A[3:0], B[3:0], Cin, S[3:0], c[0]); // sample structural code
endmodule // Koge_64
```

Comment: It was the position of the vectors. Thank you got it working.